# Trying to parse an uploaded pdf to split into chunks using Langchain's

Tags: openai-api, pdf.js, langchain, pdfjs-dist, langchain-js

```
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from 'langchain/text_splitter';
import { WebPDFLoader } from 'langchain/document_loaders/web/pdf';
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist';

///...code here handling file reading 

 const handleLoadPDF = async () => {
    if (uploadedFile) {
      const blob = new Blob([uploadedFile], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const loader = new WebPDFLoader(blob, {
        pdfjs: () => import("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.mjs"),
        workerSrc: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`,
      });

      try {
        // Load the PDF document
        const pdfDocument = await loader.load();
        const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
          chunkSize: 1000, // Adjust the chunk size as needed
          chunkOverlap: 200, // Adjust the chunk overlap as needed
        });

        // Split the document into text chunks
        const splitDocs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(pdfDocument);
        console.log({ splitDocs });

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        // Handle errors as needed
      }
    }
  };
```

```
pdf-W4I3FICS.js?v=815f6208:48416 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified
    at getWorkerSrc (pdf-W4I3FICS.js?v=815f6208:48416:23)
    at PDFWorker2.PDFWorker_initialize [as _initialize] (pdf-W4I3FICS.js?v=815f6208:48476:38)
    at new PDFWorker2 (pdf-W4I3FICS.js?v=815f6208:48454:22)
    at getDocument (pdf-W4I3FICS.js?v=815f6208:47858:72)
    at WebPDFLoader.load (langchain_document_loaders_web_pdf.js?v=815f6208:63:29)
    at async loadPDF (Input.jsx:88:18)
```

Keep getting this error despite linking a workerSrc for PDFjs, tried this with sample code on Langchain's documentation and still get the same error. Does anyone know what I need to do? Thank you!

I've tried using sample code from a similar issue on GitHub, but this gave me the same error
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/issues/3787

Comment: ```pdfjs: () => import("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.mjs"),
workerSrc: "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.mjs" ```

Changed that part of the code to above, I decided to use the worker provided in the legacy version (as langchain uses legacy pdfjs), but I get the same error @K-J

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either, unfortunately, I'm just faced with a different error `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/pdfjs-dist_legacy_build_pdf__worker__mjs.js?v=2d8bcfbc' does not provide an export named 'default'`